# Is there always a primitive m-th root of unity with imaginary part bigger than 1/2

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $m$ be a positive integer.

I need the existence of a primitive $m$-th root of unity $\zeta_m$ such that its imaginary part is strictly greater than $1/2$.

We can write $\zeta_m = \exp(2\pi i a/m)$ for some $a$ coprime to $m$.

The condition above boils down to $\sin(2 \pi a /m ) > 1/2$. This just means that $$ \frac{m}{12} <  a < \frac{5m}{12}.$$ So I'm looking for the existence of an integer $a$ coprime to $m$ such that $$ \frac{m}{12} < a < \frac{5m}{12}. $$

Is this always possible?

Probably I need that $m> 12$. For $m=12$, there is no such $a$. It's ok if it doesn't work for a finite number of $m$.

Comment: By Bertrand's Postulate, which is a theorem, there is a prime between $k$ and $2k$ if $k>2$.

Comment: @André: That's not quite enough, since it might divide $m$.

Comment: @joriki: I was giving a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Bertrand's postulate, there is always a prime number between $\lceil m/12\rceil$ and $2\lceil m/12\rceil$ and one between $2\lceil m/12\rceil$ and $4\lceil m/12\rceil$. For sufficiently large $m$ we have $4\lceil m/12\rceil\lt5m/12$. For sufficiently large $m$, these primes cannot both divide $m$, so at least one of them is coprime to $m$.

Comment: Beautiful. Note that $4[m/12] < 4(m/12 + 1)  < 5m/12$ iff $m>12$.

Comment: How big should I take $m$ though such that these primes won't both divide $m$?

Comment: Well their product is at least $2 \lceil m/12\rceil^2$, so as long as this exceds $m$, you know for sure that they can't both divide $m$.

Comment: You're completely right user9176. I guess this gives something like  m > 12^2/2 =72

Comment: Also, one more comment: There is a theorem by Chebashev which sais that there exists $N$ so that for all $n>N$ there are $k$ primes between $N$ and $2N$. This also follows from the Prime Number Theorem. Then using Joriki's idea with $k=2$, you get a shorter proof that there are only finitely many numbers for which your statement can fail, but unfortunatelly you don't get an estimate on how big this "finitely many" is. The above solution is nicer.

Comment: @Rayleigh: I did a computer search; the only values of $m$ less than $72$ for which the desired $a$ doesn't exist are $1$ through $4$ and $12$.